# In R, how can I match the first 3 characters of values from 2 different columns

Tags: r, match

```
ColA   ColB

D41    D410
D56    D411
D561   D412
D58    D60
D600   D70
```

In R, how can I get the values where the **first 3 characters of 2 different columns are matching?** In the above example, it means D41, D410, D411, D412, D600 and D60 are the matching results.

Is it possible to do with a combination of gsub and dplyr's filter function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `substr` to get the substring based on positions and then do the comparison (`==` - if we need elementwise comparison)

```
substr(df1$ColA, 1, 3) == substr(df1$ColB, 1, 3)
```

Or use `%in%` for doing whole column comparison

```
v1 <- c(df1$ColA[substr(df1$ColA, 1, 3) %in% substr(df1$ColB, 1, 3)],
         df1$ColB[substr(df1$ColB, 1, 3) %in% substr(df1$ColA, 1, 3)])
unique(v1)
#[1] "D41"  "D600" "D410" "D411" "D412" "D60"
```

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
list(df1, df1[2:1]) %>% 
     map( ~  .x %>%
       reduce(., ~  
         keep(.x,  substr(.x, 1, 3) %in%  substr(.y, 1, 3)))) %>% 
         flatten_chr
#[1] "D41"  "D600" "D410" "D411" "D412" "D60"
```

---

Or using

```
Reduce(`==`, lapply(df1, substr, 1, 3))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ColA = c("D41", "D56", "D561", "D58", "D600"), 
ColB = c("D410", "D411", "D412", "D60", "D70")), class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
install.packages("data.table")
library(data.table)
Matching <- df[substr(ColA, 1, 3) == substr(ColB, 1, 3)]
Matching_values <- substr(Matching$ColA, 1, 3)
```

Alternatively, if you do not want to use data.table, this will work on common data.frames:

```
Matching <- df[substr(df$ColA, 1, 3) == substr(df$ColB, 1, 3),]
Matching_values <- substr(Matching$ColA, 1, 3)
```

Comment: @akrun Sigh... I did not even read your code. We posted a common `data.frame` solution.

Comment: @akrun I added `Matching_values` to both solutions in my second edit. Good night bud.

Answer (score 1):

Set theory might come in handy here too, with `intersect`:

```
x <- unlist(df1, use.names=FALSE)
x[substr(x,1,3) %in% Reduce(intersect, Map(substr, df1, 1, 3))]
#[1] "D41"  "D600" "D410" "D411" "D412" "D60"
```

Comment: This one is a good one.  I was also tinkering with `Reduce` `intersect`, but didn't go further